# Corrupted data showing full size but no data

Tags: windows, hard-drive, file-corruption, hex-editor

Recently I recovered my data and one partition got damaged.Every kind of file on it shows its size and covers it on disk but when I open files in HxD it shows all bits as 0.Someone suggested its kind of a virus but I'm not sure.I tried some programs to recover corrupt data but all in vain.So any **Superuser** who can help me beat this situtaion?

Comment: If all the files contain all zeros then you are out of luck. Restore from your backups. *You have backups, right?*

Comment: **BACKUP** well that's the where problem arises or else I wouldn't have even asked in first place.But if every bit is zero how it has maintained it's size

Comment: The size is not stored with the file contents.

Comment: A bit set to 0 takes up just as much space as a bit set to 1. Anyhow it's perfectly normal, and expected that recovered data will often be corrupt, many times beyond usability.   Since there's nothing in the world that can magically recreate usable data from nothing, you're out of luck unless you have a valid backup.